# How to encrypt cookies on android apps using Phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, security, cordova, cookies

I created a Phonegap/Cordova based Android app which uses cookies, e.g. for session authentication/automatic sign in. During a security review the concerns were raised that if an attacker could get hold of the phone, he could read out the cookies and hijack the users's session.

Is there a way to programmatically encrypt the device's storage or prevent access to the cookies using Android OS 4.0 and up? I would prefer (but not insist on) a solution that is easily integrated with Phonegap/Cordova.

Comment: I would love an answer to how to protect Cookies as well. I've tried the http header Cache-Control: no-cache="Set-Cookie" but the webview still writes the session id cookie into sqlite database.

Comment: I opened an issue on the apache jira describing the circumstances around this security issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9641

Comment: tinytiger - Have you resolved this issue? If now, mind if i edit the ticket? I have a tonne of research and directions attempting to resolve it....

Comment: @Stevko be my guest ;)

Comment: @Stevko did you found any solution to above problem

Answer (score 3):

Security-wise this is absolutely a non-issue, because an attacker would need to obtain an unlocked device, in order to hijack an ongoing session. Therefore the idea to encrypt session cookies is pretty absurd - besides the cookies will be set automatically, without the least possibility to hook into there.

And even if one could encrypt them, when an unlocked device with an ongoing session can be obtained, this would not prevent anything at all. This concept is flawed and not well thought of.

The most simple solution to the problem: If not wanting to let the `WebView` save session cookies to internal storage, simply don't use the `WebView` to obtain them - then it obviously won't save them.

And I'd first would like to see *proof of concept* to get around the [encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/full-disk) on a locked device. When having a rooted device with debug-bridge enabled and screen-lock disabled, which would provide an attack vector, the security problem is a whole other than the `WebView` default cookie storage facility.

Comment: what if the device is rooted and some sort of malicious code sends the cookies to another device while in session?

Comment: @Patriot the IP won't match. It would need to use the cookies from the same IP (assuming the server-side checks if the session ID and the IP address match, which is generally a good practice); _server-side_ sessions are generally rather a server-side concern - while the cookies only work for one IP address and expire soon. Adding another layer, alike the package signature fingerprint, is not uncommon (prevents modification).

Comment: thank. I am asking because I am in the exact same situation. A government audit on one of our clients raised the same concern and refuse to authorize the release of their mobile app (financial). I read everywhere that it is a non issue so either we have to challenge it or find a way to encrypt the cookies even if it does not really add much to the security. Imagine they are on the same wifi, they would have the same IP. Would it be a vulnerability?

Comment: "checks if the session ID and the IP address match" literally no-one does that.

Comment: @MartinFürholz Onely because this may happen transparently, does not mean nobody does it. Without it, you'd permit session hijacking.